# Is there media player with support of multiple genre tags

Tags: mp3, music, media-player, tags, foobar2000

A lot of songs have multiple genre, for example a song can be jazz, electronic and vocal. I'd like to be able to find the song when I look at either of the genres.

I use foobar and it doesn't have support for multiple genre.

Is there a media player for windows that has support for multiple tags? or how do you go around that?

one other way I'd like to use it. is I'd like to use it as a playlists. for example, I want to specify what songs I'd like to play at the beginning of the evening and which I'd like to play at the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None of the major media players (Windows Media Player, Winamp, etc.) has this feature, but I think [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) has support for multiple genres. Haven't tried it myself, but here is a screenshot I found:

[image: MediaMonkey multiple genres]

To add multiple genre tags, separate each genre with a ';' (semicolon).

**Update:** It seems [MusicBee](http://www.majorgeeks.com/MusicBee_d5962.html) is another player that has this feature. It can handle multiple artists and genres.

Answer (score 7):

Foobar2000 does have support for multiple genres. Separate the genres with a semicolon when editing tags, like this: "Punk; Rock". A track tagged that way will show up under both Punk and Rock genres.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Media Player can handle multiple genres, just separate them with semicolons (;)

Answer (score 0):

MediaMonkey is the way to go if you want to add multiple genres to a MP4 file.
Once MediaMonkey is downloaded and opened. Click on File and open your file. Once it has been opened in MediaMonkey, right click on your file in MediaMonkey and click on Properties, then add your genres in the Genre section. When adding multiple use ; to seperate. For example, Action; Comedy; Crime. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.

I tried MediaMonkey but when you need to search for only tracks that are both genre A and genre B, you have to write logical queries in the search form like "genre:A AND genre:B" otherwise if you just type the genre names "A B" it will find all tracks that are of genre A OR of genre B.

On the contrary, with **MusicBee** you just type the two genres and voilà you are showed only those tracks that are genre A AND genre B. Also MusicBee looks way better and more modern (even after applying themes to MediaMonkey).

MusicBee is also completely free and there is an API available that allows developers to enhance it and most of the ones done already are open source.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add up to two 'genres' by using the 'grouping' function in iTunes I stumbled upon.
It's not ideal but it is at least a way, see the article [here, at Instructables.com](https://www.instructables.com/id/Sortable-Sub-Genre-with-iTunes-11-using-Grouping/).

Enjoy!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for your contribution. Providing the link for reference is useful, but you must also [include the essential information](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) in the post. Please [edit your answer](//superuser.com/posts/1348150/edit) so it contains that information. You might also like to take the [Tour] and read the [Answer] page, to better familiarise yourself with this site.